# Divide web page into two parts with clickable images in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, graphics

I am new to web developing and I need a small help. I want to divide web page into two parts as shown below:

[image]

How can I do this using java script or any necessary technique?

Can Somebody provide me a code or link to refer?

Comment: Could you explain more precisely what you want? Also, are these separate web pages? Or do you just want content on the left and the right?

Comment: Assume this is home page. When Click left hand side image it goes to golf.html page and when click right hand side image it goes to football.html page

Comment: Do you know how to have `img` tags function as links? Or use a image map in HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS3 supports irregular polygon shapes for things like `<DIV>`.  Check out the W3 Specifications for `clip-path` [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html).  The idea being that you can have one DIV clipped on top of the other.  I'll attempt to put together a JSFiddle shortly.  In the meantime, you can read about [CSS Shapes](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/).

Also, as others have pointed out, you can use a client-side or server side `<map>`.  Please also refer to the W3 specifications, [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp).

Comment: @Nicolas - the image was updated. Please use the link at [http://i.stack.imgur.com/xrFXY.jpg](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xrFXY.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Try an image map. Draw a polygon along the lightning splitter.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map)